# How to run the latest docker container I created?

Tags: docker

When I'm debugging my Dockerfile, y constantly need to run these two commands:

```
$ docker build -t myuser/myapp:mytag - < myapp.docker # to create the container
$ docker run -i -t myuser/myapp:mytag /bin/bash       # to enter the container and see what's going on when something went wrong
```

("mytag" is usually something like "production", "testing", or "development". Not sure if I'm supposed to use tags this way)

But now the second command doesn't seem to work anymore: it's starting an old container. If I list all the containers with `$ docker images`, I see my tagged container in the 3rd place, and other untagged containers before it. If I use the ID of the 1st container it works fine, but it will be annoying to do it that way, I will have to search for its ID every time.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the `- < myapp.docker` do in `docker build -t myuser/myapp:mytag - < myapp.docker`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to be clear about *containers* vs *images*. It sounds like your *tagged image* is 3rd in the list of images, and that you believe the first image that only has n ID really should be tagged but it isn't. This probably means that there's a problem building the image. The `docker build` output is [verbose by default](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/pull/1194) and should show you the problem.

As an aside, I'm not entirely sure about your use case but the idea of having different containers for development, testing and production is an anti-pattern. The entire point is to minimize differences between execution environments. In most cases you should use the same image but provide different environment variables to configure the application as desired for each environment. But again, I'm sure there are reasons to do this and you may have a legitimate one.

Comment: So what's the difference between a container and an image? Yes there are problems in the newly created image, so I wanted to enter it and see what happened. Eg: If it didn't find a file it just downloaded, I want to go inside and run "ls" or whatever because I might have made a typo.

Comment: An image can be used as the parent for new containers. It's a subtle but important difference in this context. See [the docs](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/terms/container/). 

To answer your follow up question, you can do exactly what you did in the question to help debug: use `docker run` with `bash` on the last image that was created and poke around.

Comment: But my original question is "how to run the latest container" (or image, ok). Is there a way to do that, other than finding what its ID is, and then copy/paste it? Because every time I have an error I will have to run "docker images" and parse the result with my eyes, move the mouse to the right place, carefully select the relevant bit etc., which is time and mental energy consuming. I still don't know the answer.

Comment: Two things. 1) `docker ps -l` will show you the last run container. You'll still have to copy and paste the ID unless you do something like `docker ps -l | awk '/^[0-9a-f]/{print $2}'` to just get the ID and not copy & paste. 2) The output from `docker build` will show you the container ID right before the step that fails.

Comment: @BenWhaley `docker ps -l | awk '/^[0-9a-f]/{print $2}'` gives me the image of the last container, not the ID. To get the only the ID, I can use the `-q` (quiet) option, i.e. `docker ps -l -q`.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to start and attach a container using:

```
docker start -i #ContainerID
```

Comment: "Just" have to start - i.e. copy and paste or manually type something non-deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use:

```
run_most_recent_container() { docker exec -it `docker ps -a --no-trunc -q | head -n 1` bash; }
```

Comment: `docker ps -lq` gives the most recent container ID, no need to filter the output of `docker ps -a`.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a few shortcuts that I've added to my .bashrc for easier development:

```bash
alias docker='sudo docker'
alias docker_clean_images='sudo docker rmi $(docker images -a --filter=dangling=true -q)'
alias docker_clean_ps='sudo docker rm $(docker ps --filter=status=exited --filter=status=created -q)'
alias dockerbuild='sudo docker build -m 4g -t "myname:latest" .'
alias dockerrun="sudo docker run -v path/to/dir/with/dockerfile/ -it myname /bin/bash"
```

By making sure I don't keep images around, I usually run the latest one, and since you can throw any parameters into the aliases, you can probably substitute one where you sort and filter `docker container list` by date (one of the other answers has that, I think)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).